# What is the difference between loading data using the = operator or from the Literal Pool?

Tags: assembly, arm

So I am learning ARM Assembly and have come across two methods of loading in data from memory.

**Method 1: Using the '=' operator**

```
.section    .data
number:     .word 0x8

.section    .text
.global     _start
_start:
    LDR R1, =number
    LDR R1, [R1]
```

**Method 2: Using the Literal Pool**

```
.section    .data
number:     .word 0x8

.section    .text
.global     _start
_start:
    LDR R1, address_of_number
    LDR R1, [R1]

address_of_number: .word number
```

Both of these methods do the same thing. They load in the address of `number` which exists in the `.data` section and then load in the actual value stored at that address.

So I am wondering if there is a difference between the two methods? I have read that the `=` operator is similar to the `*` in C. So then what is the purpose of using the Literal Pool where `address_of_number` exists to store the address?

Comment: When you do `LDR R1, =number`, the address of `number` will automatically be placed in the literal pool for you by the assembler, and the `=number` part will then be replaced by `[PC, #somevalue]`.

Comment: Note that `LDR R1, address_of_number` will also be converted into a PC-relative load. But in that case it's a value that you have placed there explicitly.

Comment: I think the main difference is that in the second case, you get to specify explicitly where the literal is placed in memory, while in the first case, the assembler decides for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, assembly language is specific to the tool not the target.  This syntax is not supported by all of the ARM assemblers and it is not supported equally by the ones that do support it.  My understanding is
that gnu is the most feature rich with respect to this address of thing.

Second....Just try it...

```
ldr r0,=0x1234567
nop
nop
nop


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <.text+0x10>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   01234567    .word   0x01234567
```

or

```
ldr r0,hello
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x12345678

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <hello-0x10>:
   0:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <hello>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)

00000010 <hello>:
  10:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

Identical machine code, no difference.

But if you do this

```
ldr r0,=0x00000104
ldr r0,=0x11000000
ldr r0,=0x20000001
ldr r0,=0x0ffffff0

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a00f41    mov r0, #260    ; 0x104
   4:   e3a00411    mov r0, #285212672  ; 0x11000000
   8:   e3a00212    mov r0, #536870913  ; 0x20000001
   c:   e3e002ff    mvn r0, #-268435441 ; 0xf000000f
```

gnu assembler, at least, will choose a different instruction for you (the ldr .. = is a pseudo instruction)(other assemblers may not, nor are
not necessarily expected to do this).

But as expected if you:

```
ldr r0,hello
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x11000000
```

you get

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <hello-0x10>:
   0:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <hello>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)

00000010 <hello>:
  10:   11000000    .word   0x11000000
```

There are times where you may wish to control exactly where the pool is
or you may specifically wish to force a pc-relative load.  Or wish to
control everything one to one like one often hopes with assembly language.

Now if you know how the encoding works

```
mov r0,#0x00000104
mov r0,#0x00000101

test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:3: Error: invalid constant (101) after fixup
```

The first one will encode the second will not (earlier arm instructions).  And then you have to go back and change the code to an ldr r0,=

It is personal preference if you start with the ldr = or finish with it.  Now you need to understand that there are multiple arm
instruction sets and different architecture versions.  Thumb,
thumb2, and arm have different immediate encoding rules, so what works for one of these does not necessarily work for the other.  But, at least for gnu assembler, the ldr = will choose the optimal instruction.